# Counting duplicate records in SQL, then adding the number of duplicate records to a records quantity and deleting the rest

Tags: sql, database

I did a lot of searching and tried to write it myself. I would like to write to a SQL query to count the number of duplicate entries, then add the number of duplicate entries to the quantity of the first entry available. This is for a game that I'm working on.

First entry being the first CustomerID,ItemID,Var1 to show up. since we need to sort this all by those 3 fields.

A duplicate entry is where ItemID and Var1 are the same, then we want add to add the quantity of the duplicate record to the first record. Inventory ID is irreverent to this as that is the primary key. We can't add records either that have different CustomerIDs

The columns are

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersInventory]
     ( [InventoryID] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
       [CustomerID]  int NOT NULL ,
       [CharID] int NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)) ,
       [BackpackSlot] int NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
       [ItemID] int NOT NULL,
       [LeasedUntil] datetime NOT NULL,
       [Quantity] int NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
       [Var1] int NOT NULL DEFAULT ((-1)),
       [Var2] int NOT NULL DEFAULT ((-1)),
       [Durability] int NULL )
```

Comment: Can you please share the structures of your tables? Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: You need to specify what a "duplicate" means to you. Not just show the columns present in the table.

Comment: I'm using Navicat Premium. Here is the structure
`code 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersInventory] (
[InventoryID] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ,
[CustomerID] int NOT NULL ,
[CharID] int NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)) ,
[BackpackSlot] int NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)) ,
[ItemID] int NOT NULL ,
[LeasedUntil] datetime NOT NULL ,
[Quantity] int NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)) ,
[Var1] int NOT NULL DEFAULT ((-1)) ,
[Var2] int NOT NULL DEFAULT ((-1)) ,
[Durability] int NULL 
) `

Comment: Please use the "Edit" link to edit your question. You are still not telling people what a "duplicate" is.4

Comment: @NeilLunn Is that better? Sorry i'm trying to explain best I can, it's techncially not a duplicate, but we don't want the same ItemID and Var1 where CustomerID = customerID

Comment: What is the `first record` means? The record with minimum `InventoryID`? What would you do to the rest of the dup records? delete them? If you keep the rest records, the `Quantity` would be increased infinitly.

Comment: @JaugarChang Yes that's the intent to delete records after we add the quantity of the record deleted that follows the same CustomerID , ItemID, and Var1. InventoryID is the primary key but we are just concerned with stacking items in the inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description of the issue, sounds like you need something like the code below.

In essence you need to first calculate the sums of all the unique items, then remove all the duplicates and finally update the quantity of items that are left

```
-- Temporary table to hold the sums
declare @tempSum table
      ( CustomerID int,
        ItemID int,
        Var1   int,
        InventoryID int,
        Quantity    int )

-- Get the sum of quantity per Customer, Item and Var1
-- This also get the first InvetoryID, assuming that the smallest number is the first one
insert @tempSum
     ( CustomerID,
       ItemID,
       Var1,
       InventoryID,
       Quantity )
select CustomerID,
       ItemID,
       Var1,
       min(InventoryID),
       sum(Quantity)
  from UsersInventory
 group by CustomerID,
          ItemID,
          Var1

begin transaction
  -- Remove duplicate items
  delete usi
    from UsersInventory usi
           join
         @tempSum       tmp on tmp.CustomerID   = usi.CustomerID
                           and tmp.ItemID       = usi.ItemID
                           and tmp.Var1         = usi.Var1
                           and tmp.InventoryID <> usi.InventoryID -- This ensures all items get deleted that are didn't mark as our firsts

  -- Update the quantity that we summed earlier
  update usi
     set Quantity = tmp.Quantity
    from UsersInventory usi
           join
        @tempSum        tmp on tmp.CustomerID  = usi.CustomerID
                           and tmp.ItemID      = usi.ItemID
                           and tmp.Var1        = usi.Var1
                           and tmp.InventoryID = usi.InventoryID

commit transaction
```

Comment: Okay so it works great, except I have one issue with Var2 not stacking, it doesn't matter if it's -1 or whatever ID it is since the game checks it once you login. How can we get this to stack with the other items as well? @BerndLinde

Comment: If you mean that it should be also part of splitting the quantity between items, then you just need to add it to the list of columns that are being used to calculate the sum of quantities

Comment: Nahh, I want all the items to stack regardless of Var2, but it seems that it only stacks all the items with Var2 = -1, or var2 = whatever ID it should be at. @BerndLinde so I'll end up with 2 stacks of the same item if that makes sense.

Comment: Then you have something different in either your itemid or var1, depending on var2. In the summing code I showed, Var2 is not referenced at all, so it should not generate any splitting of stacks. Have a look at the data before and after the summing, if things still seem weird, you will need to ask another question to prevent extensive discussions on this question/answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table T1 as (
select t1.*,count(*)-1 as records_quantity from T t1 group by t1.CustomerID,t1.ItemID,t1.Var1);

delete from T;

insert into T (select * from T1);
```